# AfterUpdate Event in Access 2007

Tags: database, ms-access-2007

I have an Access 2007 database being used for a website. The user can create events on the site, once an event is created it can be set to 'Active' or 'Inactive'. Also, when an event gets created an entry in the Calendar table is created for that event.  What I want to happen is, when an event is set to 'Inactive' I want the event to be deleted from the Calendar table.   Ideally I want to add trigger to the table, but Access 2007 does not have these.  Is there any other way I could accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INNER JOIN the Calendar and Events tables on their common field (event_id?).  Then add a WHERE clause:

```
WHERE Events.Status = 'Active'
```

That query would ignore Calendar rows for Inactive events.